# How sort XML using XSLT ascending order

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have write this XSLT to view bus stop information  but I want to ask how can I make the order in ascending  stop number. can someone give me a hand in how to sorted

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
      <xsl:element name="body">
        <table style="width:720px" border="3">
          <tr>
            <td>Stop #</td>
            <td>Route #</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>latitude</td>
            <td>longitude</td>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//stop" />
        </table>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="stop">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@number" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="routes" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="location/latitude" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="location/longitude" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: in future it would help if you can provide an example of the input XML in the question, as well as the XSLT you've tried so far.

Comment: I try to add but the system will not allow me to post it because it make my question  mostly code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sort in apply-templates like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//stop">
    <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="@number" data-type="number"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```